# Javascript open.window get field value then insert value into parent window?

Tags: javascript, forms, window.open

We have a checkout process where we want some additional information from the customers account to be bundled with the order. So I want my script to open the customers account page get a field value and insert that value into the Submit Order Form on the parent page.

```
  function openWin() {

myWindow = window.open("https://customer/accountpage.php", "myWindow", "width=200, height=100");

fieldval = myWindow.document.getElementById("accountinfo").value;

document.getElementById("formfield").innerHTML = fieldval;
}
```

It opens up the account page just fine but it seems it is getting caught up on getting the value from the child page. I am not sure what I am doing wrong any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please define "it is getting caught up on". What happens? An error occurs? You get a wrong value? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

After trying for  a while, I figured it out the code Alexander O'mara provided was correct but the one thing I was missing after that was instead of .innerHTML = fieldval; it just had to be .value = fieldval; apparently because it is an input it would like us to use .value instead .innerHTML

Alexander O'mara correct code

```
function openWin() {
myWindow = window.open("https://customer/accountpage.php", "myWindow",     "width=200, height=100");
myWindow.addEventListener('load', function() {
    fieldval = myWindow.document.getElementById("accountinfo").value;
    document.getElementById("formfield").value= fieldval;
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you open another window using `window.open`, the contents will not be loaded or ready yet. Assuming the documents are from the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), one way to solve this would be to use the `load` event.

Also, you need to use `value` for input elements, not `innerHTML`.

```
function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("https://customer/accountpage.php", "myWindow", "width=200, height=100");
    myWindow.addEventListener('load', function() {
        fieldval = myWindow.document.getElementById("accountinfo").value;
        document.getElementById("formfield").value = fieldval;
    });
}
```

Comment: After trying for  a while, I figured it out the code Alexander O'mara provided was correct but the one thing I was missing after that was instead of .innerHTML = fieldval; it just had to be .value = fieldval; apparently because it is an input it would like us to use .value instead .innerHTML

Comment: @alexRoseland Yep, `input` elements don't contain HTML.